# Running "find" and piping the output to "wc"/"sort", inside an outer "find -exec"

Tags: shell, automation, find

I've a folder used by [imapsync](https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync) to store its own cache. Such a folder contains a subfolder for each of the mailbox I'm syncing, and nothing more:

```
[dv@monitor] find * -maxdepth 0 -type d | wc -l
126
[dv@monitor] find * -maxdepth 0  | wc -l
126
```

Every subfolder replicates the mailbox structure of the related user/mailbox (*note: `imapsync` keeps track of the destination mail-server, so it adds also a reference to it, kept as an additional folder structure: `10.0.1.235` in the examples below*).

```
[dv@monitor] find director -type d
director
director/10.0.1.235
director/10.0.1.235/director
director/10.0.1.235/director/Deleted Items
director/10.0.1.235/director/Deleted Items/Deleted Items
director/10.0.1.235/director/Contacts
director/10.0.1.235/director/Contacts/Contacts
[....]
director/10.0.1.235/director/INBOX
[...]
```

Inside every subfolder `imapsync` store a file for each of the messages sync-ed:

```
[dv@monitor] ls -l segreteria/10.0.1.235/segreteria/INBOX/INBOX | head -n 10
totale 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 19 set 23:36 1000_109
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 19 set 23:36 10009_1342
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 19 set 23:36 10011_1343
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 19 set 23:36 10013_1344
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 19 set 23:36 10028_1345
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 19 set 23:36 10042_1346
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 19 set 23:36 10046_1347
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 19 set 23:36 10048_1348
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 19 set 23:36 10050_1349
```

Now, as I'm currently troubleshooting `imapsync` issues,  I need to quickly identify mailboxes that have surely had problems with syncing. Basically, **I simply need to count the number of files stored within each of first-level folders**.

As I'm a fan of the "*find is a great program. Learn of it!*" concept, my first guess have been something like:

```
[**NOT WORKING**] find * -type d -maxdepth 0 -exec 'find {} -type f | wc -l' \;
```

but it didn't worked.

After more than 30 minutes of internet-based-searching-and-learning, and even after reading [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307015/how-do-i-include-a-pipe-in-my-linux-find-exec-command), I've been (mildly) successful with:

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec sh -c "echo -n {} ; echo -n : ; find {} -type f | wc -l" \;
```

Please note that, in the above `find` the first `{}` got correctly expanded by the first-level folder name, while the second `{}` got correctly expanded with each of the file herein contained.

Unfortunatly the output is in the form `<mailbox>:<number_of_messages>` like:

```
 director:25
 sv:25
 segreteria:11532
 registration:146
 newsletter:240
```

What I was still missing is a trivial form to `sort` the output, based on the number of messages. Should the output be reversed (`<number_of_messages>:<mailbox>`), a simple:

```
 .... | sort -n
```

would have solved my needs, **with only 9 additional characters**.

So I tried changing the order of the `echo` inside the nested `find`. Something like:

```
[**not working**] find * -type d -maxdepth 0 -exec sh -c "find {} -type f | wc -l ; echo -n : ; echo -n {} ;" \;
```

but it didn't worked, probably due to the need to expand `{}` in reverse order (first occurrence of `{}` being expanded by second `find`; second occurrenct of `{}` being expanded by first `find`).

So, after all of above introduction, can someone point me how to adapt this (properly working) one-liner:

> `find * -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec sh -c "echo -n {} ; echo -n : ; find {} -type f | wc -l" \;`

in such a way to reverse the output (`<number>:<mailbox>` or, even better `<number><space><mailbox>`)?

---

*(P.S.: obviously there are plenty of ways to achieve this very goal. As for myself, I would have no problem in firing a 3/4 lines perl-script to split/reverse the output of each line. I'm interested in solutions that will require a "slight-addition" of characters; something like `| sort -n`. Anyway every hints/suggestions, are welcomed)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to adapt the output of your nested `find` oneliner to the default behaviour of `sort`, I propose you tell `sort` where to find the sorting key:

```
... | sort -t: -k2n
```

This is of course assuming that none of your first-level directory names contains a colon.

Comment: Based on the `-d`/`-f` parameter of the `cut` command, I searched for something similar within `sort` man pages. Even if I regularly rely on the `-n` and `-k` options of `sort`, I (unforgivebly) missed the `-t` you mentioned in your answer. Thanks for pointing it. I promise to be a better man-page-reader, from now on :-)